# What is the meaning of "bissig und böss"

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context, german-to-english, poetry, literature

In working on a translaion I would like to know if "bissig und böss" could
be interpreted as  "caustic and naughty" in relations to animals?

Comment: Can you please give more contexts for your problem and elaborate what you already know about those words (e.g., from a dictionary)? This may help your question being reopened.

Answer (score 3):

Bissig relates to the verb "beissen" - So it's actually biting.

"Böss" should be "böse" - so "bad", or "evil" (your "naughty" is not wrong, though)

The whole thing, provided it relates to animals, as you said, thus is best translated to

> biting and bad

In relation to humans, the translation would probably be a bit different, like

> snappy and evil